# Using if inside macro

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to write a function which would return different values depending on argument.
I've written:

```
define function
ifeq($(1),a)
aaaa
else
bbbb
endif
endef

$(info MSG: $(call function,a))
```

I get output:

```
MSG: ifeq(a,a)
aaaa
else
bbbb
endif
```

That is the whole body of the function instead of *aaaa*.

How should I rewrite the function or change the way I call it in order to get text only from the matching if branch?

UPDATE:
Also I've tried to enclose function call in *eval*, but get *missing separator* error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use `filter-out`, than use `filter` twice:

```
$(if $(filter-out $(1),$(2)),bbbb,aaaa)
```

(note I had to invert the legs of the conditional, because `filter-out` will give output (thus being "true" for `if`) when they do not match.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with such a decision. Perhaps not very elegant, but still it does what I need:

```
txtcmp = $(and $(filter $(1),$(2)),$(filter $(2),$(1)))

define function
$(if $(call txtcmp,$(1),a),aaaa,bbbb)
endef

$(info MSG: $(call function,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account implementation of `txtcmp` you need a function for testing if two arguments are equal. If they are, return one value, otherwise return another.

Your solution looks OK, however can be improved a little:

```
function = $(if $(call txtcmp,$(1),a),aaaa,bbbb)
```

Note, there is another text search function - `findstring`. Using it instead of `filter` will produce slightly different results:

```
txtcmp = $(and $(filter $(1),$(2)),$(filter $(2),$(1)))

function = $(if $(call txtcmp,$(1),a),aaaa,bbbb)

$(info MSG: $(call function,b))
$(info MSG: $(call function,a))
$(info MSG: $(call function, a))

txtcmp = $(and $(findstring $(1),$(2)),$(findstring $(2),$(1)))

$(info MSG: $(call function,b))
$(info MSG: $(call function,a))
$(info MSG: $(call function, a))
```

Running the above makefile will output:

```
MSG: bbbb
MSG: aaaa
MSG: aaaa
MSG: bbbb
MSG: aaaa
MSG: bbbb
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```